# How to refresh a listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have done some search in Google but not able to find a useful method...Please help...
So I have a listBox that display the data from database, my function allows the user to delete one/multiple data at a time, and of course i would like to refresh my listBox accordingly.
I try for example, checkedListBox1.Refresh(); but didn't work. Please help me.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string item_name = "";
            foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                item_name = itemChecked.ToString();
                removefromdatabse2(item_name); // a function that update the database
                MessageBox.Show("successfully deleted");
               // checkedListBox1.Refresh();  , which didn't work

            }
        }
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean here? What were you expecting `Refresh()` to do?

Comment: I was expecting that my listbox has x item less after display of (Successfully deleted) if the user chose to remove x items

Comment: Also, you would probably want to refresh it once you're done with all your operations, e.g. at the end of the method. It doesn't make sense to refresh when you still have operations left that you might need to do.

Comment: RIght, i tried it, but it was the same result.

Comment: Wait, in this code, it doesn't look like you're even removing the item from the List. You have to explicitly do that. You can't just remove it from the database and expect the List to update.

Comment: oops, right....thanks so mcuh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either clear the whole listbox of its items and repopulate it from the database, or locate the item you're removing and remove it manually. Alternatively, using the "DataSource" property on the ListBox control and update the source whenever you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Delete the selected `ListBoxItem` instances from the `ListBox` (using the `ListBox.SelectedItems` property to get the selected items) and the corresponding items stored in the database. Each `ListBoxItem` instance should have a unique identifier that matches one used in the database table storing the items.
- Delete the items stored in the database that correspond to the selected items in the `ListBox`, clear the `ListBox` and reload it with the items stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Clear it and then rebind the listbox to the datasource